# Activity con listview y MapView en fragment

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragment

Hola soy muy nueva en esto y hace mucho que estoy lidiando con este problema y no puedo resolverlo, se que debe ser fácil pero no logro hacerlo.

Tengo una Activity, con un Fragment con un MapView y una List View con clientes y sus direcciones, lo que quiero hacer es que al tocar el ítem me cambie la ubicación en el mapa que ya lo instancie con la ubicación en Bs. As., como es posible hacerlo? Hice un método Market que llamo en el setOnClickItemListener pero al volver al Fragment me da un error que el GoogleMap es null!!
También intente poner el Map en la Activity pero tampoco puedo solucionarlo!!
Espero que puedan ayudarme, desde ya muchas gracias, y ya que estoy me gustaría también si me pueden recomendar algunos videos para poder aprender, desde ya muchas gracias.

```
fragment_ubicacion_avance_detalle.xml

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutUbi"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:paddingEnd="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="Ubicaciones" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ubi_avance_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/ubi_avance_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>


fragment_map.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>



MapViewFragment

package com.din.salesforce.ui.avances;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.din.salesforce.R;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapViewFragment extends Fragment {
    private Double latitud,longitud;
    private LatLng sydney;
    MapView mMapView;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    public MapViewFragment(){
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

        mMapView = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mMapView.onResume(); 

        try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
                googleMap = mMap;

                
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                   
                    return;
                }
                googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

                market(0.0,0.0);

                

            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }



    public void market(double lat, double lng){

        if (lat != 0.0 && lng != 0) {
            latitud=lat;
            longitud=lng;
            sydney = new LatLng(latitud,longitud);

        }else{
            sydney = new LatLng(-34.61315, -58.37723);
        }
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker Title").snippet("Marker Description"));
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(sydney).zoom(12).build();
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mMapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mMapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mMapView.onLowMemory();
    }
}



UbicacionAvanceDetalleActivity



        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                mapViewFragment.market(localizacion.getLatitude(),localizacion.getLongitude());
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo pondría todo en el xml de la activity, hace poco hice algo parecido pero escuchando los estados de la lista (cada que se hace scroll muevo la camara al item), tendrias un XML como este:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mapFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/locationList"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:itemCount="5"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_location"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Te dejo un ejemplo de como lo hice con kotlin, en tu caso es un poco mas sencillo porque en vez de tener ese listener feo tendrias que usar el animateCamera en tu clickListener del RecyclerView

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {

private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
private lateinit var map: GoogleMap

private val locationListAdapter by lazy { LocationListAdapter() }

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    val view = binding.root
    setContentView(view)

    setupListComponents()
    createFragment()
}

private fun setupListComponents() {
    with(binding) {
        locationList.apply {
            adapter = locationListAdapter
            LinearSnapHelper().attachToRecyclerView(locationList)
            addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
                    super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)
                    when (newState) {
                        AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE -> {
                            val visiblePosition = (locationList.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
                            val position = (visiblePosition%locationListAdapter.currentList.size)
                            val currentLocation = locationListAdapter.currentList[position]
                            createMarker(location = currentLocation)
                        }

                        else -> Unit
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
}

private fun createFragment() {
    val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment) as SupportMapFragment
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
}

override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    map = googleMap
    setupLocationList()
}

private fun setupLocationList() {
    val locationList = listOf(
        Location(
            title = "Soriana",
            coordinates = LatLng(19.6897173,-99.2266067)
        ),
        Location(
            title = "Walmart",
            coordinates = LatLng(19.6897176,-99.2256028)
        ),
        Location(
            title = "Mercado del Carmen",
            coordinates = LatLng(19.6798232,-99.2197768)
        ),
        Location(
            title = "Luna Parc",
            coordinates = LatLng(19.6619332,-99.214316)
        ),
        Location(
            title = "Suburbia",
            coordinates = LatLng(19.6535748,-99.2107012)
        )
    )

    locationListAdapter.submitList(locationList)
}

private fun createMarker(location: Location) {
    val marker = MarkerOptions().position(location.coordinates).title("Test")
    map.addMarker(marker)
    map.animateCamera(
        CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(location.coordinates, 18f),
        3000,
        null
    )
}


}
```

Te dejo el repositorio completo por si quieres ver un poco mas : https://github.com/asfroggen/MapsPlayground